# Java compiler level does not match

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-3

i am using jsf2 hibernate 4.1.4, spring 3.1 and maven 3 in eclipse helios. but i have this error when i try to add dependecy in to POM.

```
Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet.
```

what does it mean? how can i solve this error?

also i have this warning:

```
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.integrate</groupId>
  <artifactId>integrate</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>integrate</name>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <properties>
  <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>

  <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency> 

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

  <!-- JSF dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>


  <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javassist</groupId>
   <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
   <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- oracle Connector dependency -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- c3p0 dependency -->
      <dependency>
       <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
       <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
       <version>0.9.1.2</version>
  </dependency>  


 </dependencies>
```

the pic:
[image]

Comment: post your pom.xml or a  link to it using paste bin or gist on github

Comment: You need JDK 1.5 installed and setup in preference->jre

Comment: @J-16SDiZ, i installed jdk 1.6

Comment: @sami, no. You need exactly 1.5 and make it default (in eclipse preference).

Comment: @J-16SDiZ, i marked jre7 in preference.

Comment: and jre7 don't match any facets profile. I told you to set it to jdk1.5

Comment: @J-16SDiZ, please the  above pic. is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the **build** section with the **maven-compiler-plugin** to your pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you should configure project's build path.

Or you can just delete the project from eclipse workspace (without deleting from file system), remove eclipse's settings (.project, .classpath and .settings files and folders) from the project and re-import your project as an existent Maven project to your IDE. Eclipse will re-generate its settings properly.

Comment: I've edited my comment above. Please check your pom.xml's consistency running `mvn clean compile` at the root of your project. If it's OK you can choose an appropriate case for you either configure your project class path setting or delete eclipse's settings as mentioned in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me:

1. Project->Java Build Path->Libraries->JRE version
2. Project->Java Compiler-> Compiler Compliance Level
3. Project->Project Facets->Java->Version
4. If you using Maven edit in pom.xml

   ```
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <source>1.8</source>
             <target>1.8</target>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```

Comment: This worked for me @Jaeger. Compiler version of JRE Version with Project Facets Java Version should Match.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the project facets concerned with your project(**Right click on the project/ Properties/ Project Facets/ Java**).

It is just that the java version which you have installed in your system, and the one which you are specifying in the project facets of your project, might not be matching.

Comment: in priject facet java version is 1.6

Comment: So is it the one which has been installed in your system ?

Comment: i have installed jdk 7u1 in my system

Comment: Since your project is having 1.6, you should have java 6 installed and not 7

Answer (score 0):

Specify the java version for Maven in D:\maven-2.2.1\conf toolchains.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toolchains>
<toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
        <version>1.5</version> <!--This should be same as is configured via the toolchains plugin -->
        <vendor>ibm</vendor> <!--This should be same as is configured via the toolchains plugin -->
    </provides>
    <configuration>
        <jdkHome>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
</toolchain>
</toolchains>
```